# What is the limit of $\frac{e^n}{(n+4)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do we compute the limit:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^n}{(n+4)!}$

I can only think of this approach, but I am not sure that it's too valid:

We know that the terms are positive, so we would try a Squeeze Theorem approach by:

$0 < \frac{e^n}{(n+4)!} = \frac{e}{n+4} \times \frac{e}{n+3} \times ... \times \frac{e}{2} \times e < k$ where k is something related with $\frac{e^n}{n^n}$, but that limit is only giving indeterminate forms.

Comment: hint: prove that for all $ n \ge 6 $, $e^n < n!$, and use the sandwich rule

Comment: @5xum Thank you and sorry, corrections have been made

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show by the ratio test, that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^n}{(n+4)!}$ is convergent. Hence $ \frac{e^n}{(n+4)!} \to 0.$

Comment: Thank you for such an elegent way to show this. It is much simpler that what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Here's a hint:

$$\frac{e^n}{(n+4)!} = \frac{e^n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots (n+4)} = \frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4}\cdot \frac{e}{5}\cdot\frac{e}{6}\cdot\frac{e}{7}\cdots \frac{e}{n+3}\cdot \frac{e}{n+4}$$

Now, notice two things:

1. The factors (except for the first one, which is just a constant value) are all $e$, divided by something bigger than $e$.
2. There are $n$ of these factors.

Comment: Shouldn't the total no. of factors from $\frac e4$ inclusively through $\frac e{n+4}$ be $(n+1)$?

Comment: @Koro Why? The numerator is $e^n$, there are $n$ repetitions of $e$ in the numerator...

Comment: @Koro Ah, there was a slight mistake, the first factor should be $\frac{e}{5}$...

Comment: Now it looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove by induction that for all $ n \ge 6 $, $ e^n < n!$

Induction base: $ e^6 = 403.42... < 6! = 720 $.

Induction step: if $ e^n < n! $ and $ n \ge 6 $, since $ e < n $ we get that $ e ^ {n+1} < n \cdot n! < (n+1)!$

Since $ e^n < n!$ for almost all $ n $, we also get $ 0 < \frac{e^n}{(n+4)!} < \frac{n!}{(n+4)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} $ for almost all $n$, and by the sandwich rule the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{e^n}{n!} = e^n\prod_{k=2}\frac{1}{k}<\frac{e^n}{2}\prod_{k=3}\frac{1}{3}
=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{e}{3}\Big)^n<\Big(\frac{e}{3}\Big)^n.
$$
And $\frac{1}{(n+4)!} < \frac{1}{n!}$ so
$\frac{e^n}{(n+4)!}<\big(\frac{e}{3}\big)^n.$

Also, for any $x$ there exists an integer $k>x$ so this argument shows that $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ tends to zero for any positive x.